# IP Address and Site Verification

Tags: web-service, web

I just got interested in the kind of technologies that are employed in verifying the ownership of a website/domain or IP address. More specifically, a couple of online services offer the possibility of conducting vulnerability scanning without the need to install vulnerability scanners. I tried one of them and realized I had to verify ownership of my domain.

My question is, how do these verification approaches work. Can they be circumvented in some way ? The approaches I have observed in use include Google Analytics, DNS records, file upload, meta tag and some manual approaches.

UPDATE..

@yzT's answer has aided my understanding.  A related question is about leveraging browser certificate verification functionality for domain verification. I am not sure how this is possible, but given that browsers are able to validate web server's ssl certificate, can a third party application leverage this in anyway ? For example can a web application query FireFox's (or another browser) certificate store for a specific certificate being presented by an entity, claiming to own a domain ? Or request the entity to present its ssl certificate for verification through the above mentioned approach ? am not sure if this is clear enough though ...

Comment: ownership of an IP address and ownership of a domain are two completely different things. please be more specific with your question

Comment: about your update, it doesn't work that way. A browser doesn't validate a certificate, a certificate authority does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that you own a domain you have multiple methods, being the most common to add a CNAME or TXT record to your DNS, or if it's for a web server, you have the possibility to upload a temporary file (like Let's Encrypt does with the webroot plugin).

Prove that you own an IP is a little more complicated and eventually would need some signed confirmation by your ISP. You can't use file upload because it's not a 1:1 relation. For example, if you have your site in a shared hosting, the IP would be the same for many customer and you just own a VirtualHost in that IP.